# How to interface Keypad & LCD using 8051 Microcontroller

Tags: c, keil

I got a project from college, i have to do "Keypad to LCD interference using 8051 microcontroller".
 Explained: Means when i press key 1, it'll show my name on lcd, by pressing key 2, it'll show my roll number & vice versa.

I just know one thing that this can be code in keil and then we have to burn it using 8051 microcontroller . Can anyone please help me with coding ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [Interfacing Keypad with 8051 Microcontroller using Keil C](https://electrosome.com/interfacing-keypad-8051-microcontroller-keil-c/) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

[This will help you to interface the LCD and KEYPAD to 8051 micro-controller.](http://www.electronicwings.com/8051/4x4-keypad-interfacing-with-8051)
Follow the same on the link and modify the code as your requirement for the keypad. I had implemented the same for my project of developing a basic calculator with 8051.